# Woocommerce change prices for a certain country

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change the prices (e.g for switzerland CH) and add an amount to all the prices..

I have this for my functions.php, but it does not work...

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_change_price' );
function woocommerce_change_price() {
global $woocommerce;

$county     = array('CH');
$amount     = 5;

if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ){
    woocommerce_get_price += $amount;
    woocommerce_get_regular_price; += $amount;
    woocommerce_get_sale_price += $amount;
    woocommerce_order_amount_item_subtotal += $amount;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`woocommerce_get_price`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_price/) filter:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', $product, 2);

function return_custom_price($price, $product) {    
    global $post, $woocommerce;
    // Array containing country codes
    $county = array('CH');
    // Amount to increase by
    $amount = 5;
    // If the custromers shipping country is in the array
    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ){
        // Return the price plus the $amount
       return $new_price = $price + $amount;
    } else {
        // Otherwise just return the normal price
        return $price;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To do this for just one product you can simply run a check on the product id via `$post`:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', $product, 2);

function return_custom_price($price, $product) {    
    global $post, $woocommerce;
    // Array containing country codes
    $county = array('CH');
    // Get the post id 
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    // Amount to increase by
    $amount = 5;
    // If the customers shipping country is in the array and the post id matches
    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) && ( $post_id == '12' || $post_id == '5' || $post_id == '6' ) ){
        // Return the price plus the $amount
       return $new_price = $price + $amount;
    } else {
        // Otherwise just return the normal price
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Simply replace the '12' with your desired product ID. ('5' and '6' are the checkout pages respectively)

Comment: How would I do this for a single product ID?

Comment: Have edited the answer to include a check on the product id

Comment: One more problem.. it works for every site but not the cart and not the checkout! Any idea?

Comment: see edited snippet - because the product id is the also the post id, you will need to include a check on the cart and checkout page id as well

Comment: hmm it did not change :(.. isn't the '5' and '6' just checking for 2 other ids? Did not change something in the checkout pages

Comment: Yes, 5 and 6 are checking the page id's for cart and check-out. So you just need to make sure that you find your cart and check-out page id's and replace the 5 and 6 in the snippet above with your cart and check-out page id's

Comment: Ah now I got it.. it works for the cart page now.. but not for the checkout O.o this is driving me crazy